# Most efficient way of splitting String in Java

Tags: java, string, parsing, split, stringtokenizer

For the sake of this question, let's assume I have a `String` which contains the values `Two;.Three;.Four` (and so on) but the elements are separated by `;.`.

Now I know there are multiple ways of splitting a string such as `split()` and `StringTokenizer` (being the faster one and works well) but my input file is around **1GB** and I am looking for something slightly more efficient than `StringTokenizer`.

After some research, I found that `indexOf` and `substring` are quite efficient but the examples only have single delimiters or results are returning only a single word/element.

Sample code using `indexOf` and `substring`:

```
String s = "quick,brown,fox,jumps,over,the,lazy,dog";
int from = s.indexOf(',');
int to = s.indexOf(',', from+1);
String brown = s.substring(from+1, to);
```

The above works for printing `brown` but how can I use `indexOf` and `substring` to split a line with multiple delimiters and display all the items as below.

**Expected output**

```
Two
Three
Four
....and so on
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Have you done tests on various test cases and see which is "efficient"?

Comment: There's also an `indexOf` overload that takes `String`...

Comment: you mean this `string.replaceAll(";\\.", "\n");` ?

Comment: @BuhakeSindi Yes I have done tests. For a sample string on my machine using StringTokenizer took 8.0 us, split() took 23 us

Comment: Just loop, indexOf() takes a start parameter which is supposed to be the last found index.

Comment: @AvinashRaj that wouldn't be that flexible when I want to use each element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`StringTokenizer` is faster than `StringBuilder`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String str = "This is String , split by StringTokenizer, created by me";
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str);

    System.out.println("---- Split by space ------");
    while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
        System.out.println(st.nextElement());
    }

    System.out.println("---- Split by comma ',' ------");
    StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer(str, ",");

    while (st2.hasMoreElements()) {
        System.out.println(st2.nextElement());
    }
}
```

Comment: According to [JDK Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html), `StringTokenizer` is considered a Legacy class for a while now. The recommendation is to use `String.split` or something from `java.util.regex` package.

Answer (score 7):

This is the method I use for splitting large (1GB+) tab-separated files. It is limited to a `char` delimiter to avoid any overhead of additional method invocations (which may be optimized out by the runtime), but it can be easily converted to String-delimited. I'd be interested if anyone can come up with a faster method or improvements on this method.

```
public static String[] split(final String line, final char delimiter)
{
    CharSequence[] temp = new CharSequence[(line.length() / 2) + 1];
    int wordCount = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int j = line.indexOf(delimiter, 0); // first substring

    while (j >= 0)
    {
        temp[wordCount++] = line.substring(i, j);
        i = j + 1;
        j = line.indexOf(delimiter, i); // rest of substrings
    }

    temp[wordCount++] = line.substring(i); // last substring

    String[] result = new String[wordCount];
    System.arraycopy(temp, 0, result, 0, wordCount);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: You can further improve this by obtaining all the indexes at once, as indexOf loops through the String

Comment: @Sport Inside the loop, I start each search after the index of the previous occurrence (`line.indexOf(delimiter, i)`), so each character is only checked once. I could probably write an inline version of `indexOf(char, int)` to avoid the overhead of repeated method invocation.

Answer (score 5):

If you want the ultimate in efficiency I wouldn't use `Strings` at all, let alone split them. I would do what compilers do: process the file a character at a time. Use a `BufferedReader` with a large buffer size, say 128kb, and read a `char` at a time, accumulating them into say a `StringBuilder` until you get a `;` or line terminator.

Comment: Okay will give this a try and report back. Thanks

Comment: @AvinashRaj Your comment has nothing to do with my answer. Don't post irrelevant comments here.

Comment: @AvinashRaj That doesn't have anything more to do with my answer than your previous comment.